# Is possible to know if an user has updated any record using the SQL manager?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know if the updates run in the SQL manager write any log in order to know if somebody of my team has update any record

Comment: No. Not out of the box. You can add various libraries that write everything to a log but you have to turn them on beforehand

Comment: [CHANGETABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not support user, so you must use triggers with [CURRENT_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: thank you guys, I suspected it